# Apple account deletion requirement and obligations between users

Tags: ios

Apple's new policy requires the possibility to delete an account and all personal information. Imagine this scenario:

User A pays to User B in advance for a service User B provides.

User B deletes their account after getting the money

User A writes to customer support that they haven't received any service but we have absolutely no information on the User B and no way to contact them or inform legal authority on promised and paid services not provided.

How should we deal with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are situations like this that are applicable to your situation, then simply inform users that in the event of an account deletion some information will be retained via a legal document they can read when they are about to initiate account deletion.

Apple's review team is unlikely to be so thorough but even if they do ask you about it just explain why some user information has to be retained for legal purposes.

Apple states [here](https://developer.apple.com/support/offering-account-deletion-in-your-app/):

> Deleting an account removes the account from the developer’s records, along with any data associated with the account that the **developer isn’t legally required to maintain**.

Lots of apps are still retaining information after users delete their accounts because of legal requirements. For example, because of compliance regulations an investment app cannot just erase all your personal information when you delete your account.

In your case, you may want to prevent users from deleting their accounts until their transactions have all settled. I have worked on a similar situation, where users cannot initiate deletion until their balance is zero and they have no pending transfers. Have had no issues with App Store Review.